# Unexpected behaviour of Displayfunction

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have just started wrapping up some graphical display functions within larger function definitions. Here is a simple example of what works as expected. Define:

```
xyplot := 
(
a = Table[{Sin[n], Sin[2 n]}, {n, 50}];
ListPlot[a, DisplayFunction -> (Print[#]; &)];
)
```

and call

```
xyplot
```

This returns the expected graph.
However if using instead `ErrorListPlot` or `GraphicsRow`, the graphs do not display correctly. For example the error plot does not show any error bar, and is followed by the front end returning some errors. Here is a simple example that I expected to work but does not:

```
xyerrplot := 
(
b = Table[{i, RandomReal[0.5]}, {i, 10}];
ErrorListPlot[b, DisplayFunction -> (Print[#]; &)];
)
```

As a workaround the following does work:

```
xyerrplotagain := 
(
c = Table[{i, RandomReal[0.5]}, {i, 10}];
Print[ErrorListPlot[c]];
)
```

The problem experienced with `GraphicsRow` can be worked around similarly to `ErrorListPlot`. Am I missing something, or is there a bug associated with `DisplayFunction`?

Using Mathematica 11.1 on a MS Windows PC.

Comment: Just as the side note: Even the first example does not show anything (using Mathematica 11.3 frontend on macOS).

Comment: Hard do tell what the usage message means but it works if you use it like examples in docs `Show[yourStuff, DisplayFunction -> ...]`.